# Using a class method from another class in a class's class methods

Tags: ruby

Hope that title was confusing enough for everyone! The program I am recreating uses a ton of classes. The two I am working with are called "receiver" and "storage". I have a class method in the `storage` class named `store`. In my receiver class I have a class method `add`. I need the add method to call `Storage.store(object)`. The way it is setup now doesn't work but I can't seem to think of a work around. What is a different way to call a class method from a different class's class method?

```
require_relative 'storage.rb'

class Receiver

 #{PRIVATE}
  private
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, :number

 #{PUBLIC}
  public

    @@receivers = []

    def initialize(first_name, last_name, number)
      @first_name = first_name.downcase.capitalize
      @last_name = last_name.downcase.capitalize
      @number = number
      Receiver.add(@first_name,@last_name,@number)
    end

    class << self

      def add(first_name,last_name,number)
        first_name = {:first_name => first_name, :last_name => last_name, :number => number}
        @@receivers << first_name
        Storage.store({})
      end
   end
end
```

`C:/Users/sutley/Desktop/Ruby Scripts/Ruby Procs/receiver.rb:30:in 'add': uninitialized constant Class::Storage (NameError)`

Edit-----------

```
class Storage


  class << self

    def store object


    end

    def un_store first_name

    end

    def show_all
      end
    end

  end
```

Unfortunately I can't post all of the code. How ever this is all that's needed because it doesn't work even with the empty methods

Comment: Typically I would just pass a `Storage` object into the add function and call `.store` on it but I assume that's not possible here?

Comment: I might just deconstruct the Storage class and add the methods and functionality to the Receiver class

Comment: That error message is odd. Why `Class::Storage` instead of `Storage`? Can you show how `Storage` is defined?

Comment: I can't determine why, however I can determine what. It has something to do with the Receiver.add method called when initialized. If I take it out then `Storage.store` works! I put the `Storage` class up

Comment: I copy pasted the code as it is and it worked. I also called Receiver.add(params...) just to be sure. Here is how my environment is different from your. I am using a Mac, Ruby 2.1.1 and executed using RubyMine. I would recommend trying to use new version of Ruby. If that fails, consider using VM's on your Windows to run Linux and see if that works.

Comment: I'm using 1.9 and I have the classes in separate .rb files. Could that have anything to do with it?